# Optimisation of model parameters under constraints in Simulink

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, simulink

I have a model in Simulink describing the behaviour of a system depending on time dependent inputs and model parameters, that can be described as **f(a,t)**.

I have to optimise the model parameters (**a**) so that the maximum value of the function (**f**) over a determined time period (**T**) is below a cetrain value (**f0**). The problem can be described as to find

> **MAX(a)** SUCH THAT **MAX[f(a,t)] < f0** FOR EACH **t** BELONGING TO **T**

I have already solved the problem with a MATLAB script, but I want to know if it is possible to do it directly in SIMULINK

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [Simulink Design Optimizer](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/sl-design-optimization/) toolbox.